# localized electrons in the crystals

Tags: quantum-mechanics, crystals

Why electrons in low lying levels of individual atoms stay localized in their own atoms in a crystal? Doesn't this contradict Bloch's theorem?

Answer (score 4):

They do not stay localized actually. It's only that their eigenstates (which are non-local) are very close in energy, and we can choose the basis of localized states and they would be close to eigenstates with high accuracy.

You can consider the [tight-binding model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tight_binding), and take it to the limit of zero overlap of orbitals of neighboring atoms, and zero overlap integrals. That would be close to what low-level electrons in a crystal behave like.

Comment: So if there was only one electron in the crystal with lowest possible energy (1S orbital) it could be found on all nuclei with the same probability?

Comment: Yes (that would be the lowest state in the energy band, to which 1s energy level would expand to). But in that case the crystal would be unstable, because the average charge density would be positive then. To make a zero average charge density, you need to take as many electrons as protons in the nuclei. For the simpler model, consider 1 electron per 2 protons - an $\mathrm{H}_2^+$ hydrogen molecular ion.

Comment: and why these electrons couldn't conduct in Insulators if they are extended?(thanks)

Comment: Ha! That's a great question! That's because all the band is completely filled with electrons, and it consists of a complete set of wave vectors (quasimomenta). Thus, there are as many electrons moving from left to right, as moving from right to left. The total current of these electons is zero, and such bands take no part in conductivity, just the same as completely empty bands. Only partially filled bands can conduct anything, and those appear only in metals, semiconductors and such. See Fig. 1 in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_band_structure

Comment: then by applying an electric field you can destroy this balance and have current! no?

Comment: Applying an electric field (basically) leaves the states themselves. It only forces elecrons to leave some states and fill others. And that is possible only in partially filled bands, as in the conduction band in metals and semiconductors (and in the valence band in semiconductors, in the case of holes). // Your questions become wider and drift farther from the initial one, and I suggest you read a textbook on solid state physics instead. I do not feel myself able to explain all this field in such a terse format.

Answer (score 1):

In an ideal crystal at zero Kelvin, all the electrons in the low-lying states are equally to be found throughout the crystal, i.e. as per Bloch's theorem, probability of finding electrons is periodic in the crystal for a given eigenstate (and they all are almost degenerate, i.e. with a sharp energy band). If you consider tight binding method as a means to solve for eigenstates, the wavefunctions are still linear combination of atomic orbitals such that probability density is periodic in the crystal. However, at a finite temperatures, the electrons are going to be localized at atomic sites. This is because the "coupling" in the tight-binding sense is small, and any atomic vibrations (and electron-electron interactions) will destroy this coupling and localize the elecrton. This will eventually lead to each electron having its own local identity as defined by the particular lattice point. Such localization does not happen for valence electrons because they are losely bound, or they couple with neighboring atoms strongly, or the orbitals have a large spatial overlap. This means any imperfections in the periodic potential are not going to cause localization as it would for low-energy state electrons.

Comment: I did not mean Anderson localization.

Comment: This question came up again and I revisited your question (which is a very interesting and valid question). And to respond to your comment, no, I did not mean Anderson localization.